# Passing data from Node.JS to a frontend (EJS) async without passing data with initial render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have a web app that uses nodejs as a backend, and ejs for the front end... When I to pass data to ejs, I do so like this:

```
res.render('page', {data_name:data_value})
```

However, I have a part of the app where I need a data stream to periodically check the database for changes. I currently have this setup using jQuery/ajax; however, this process is running using setInterval(), and it transfers a lot of data (unnecessarily)...

A more efficient approach would be to have something in the backend listening to the database, and letting the front end know whenever a change is made...

Luckily, there is something called "change streams" in the world of mongodb, and they are able to listen for events that take place in the database...

The problem is that I do not want to re-render the entire page to pass the needed data whenever the database is changed...

Is is possible to do this task async, where I do not have to refresh the page?

Comment: Have you looked into web sockets?

Comment: @MattU no, but I'll check it out... Thanks

Comment: @MattU yeah thats exactly what I was looking for, thank you sir...

Comment: I agree about WebSockets but which database you are using, Mongodb or MySQL to suggest a good package for the listener?

Comment: @AhmedRebai mongodb!